# JavaFX XYChart.Series - Unable to set specific color/size on the data points

Tags: java, javafx, symbols, series, linechart

Im using LineChart with few series in a JavaFX project.
I have a XYChart.Series and i want to change the size/color of the data points(symbols) in the series. (i have to use LineChart)

**for some reason i am able to control the width and color of the line but i am not able to control the parameters of the data points(symbols).**

i added a part of my code that works: the line color is changing as i want:

```
   LineChart myChart;
   xAxis = new NumberAxis();
   yAxis = new NumberAxis();
   normalSeries = new XYChart.Series();
   anomalySeries = new XYChart.Series();
   lineSeries = new XYChart.Series();
   myChart = new LineChart(xAxis,yAxis);
   myChart.setAnimated(false);
   myChart.setLegendVisible(false);

     for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        normalSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(xValues.get(i),yValues.get(i)));
    }
    myChart.getData().add(normalSeries);

   for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        anomalySeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(pointsX.get(i),pointsY.get(i)));
    }
    myChart.getData().add(anomalySeries);

    lineSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(min,line.f(min)));
    lineSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(max,line.f(max)));
    myChart.getData().add(lineSeries);

    Node node =myChart.lookup(".series0.chart-series-line");
    node.setStyle("-fx-stroke: transparent;");

    Node node1 =myChart.lookup(".series1.chart-series-line");
    node1.setStyle("-fx-stroke: transparent;");

    Node node2=myChart.lookup(".series2.chart-series-line");
    node2.setStyle("-fx-stroke: grey;");
```

and this part of my code does not work: the points(symbols) are not changed at all(not even one of the points):

```
    Node node3 =myChart.lookup(".series0.chart-line-symbol");
    node3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, black; -fx-background-radius: 1px;");
    
    Node node4 =myChart.lookup(".series1.chart-line-symbol");
    node4.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red, red;");
```

What is wrong here?
thank you

Comment: Your code is working for me. Can you please provide a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to check where you are going wrong.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to change the size, but I have been using this

```
.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #5697ff, #5697ff55; }
```

in css to change the color.